react-router-dom issue with Vite react
I'm setting up react-router-dom in my Vite react app. Everything is running smoothly in dev, but when I rub my build and preview it, Im getting the following error
localhost/:1 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "react-router-dom". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

This is my App.js
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from "./Components/Home/Home";
import BlogHome from "./Components/Blog/BlogHome";
import Blog from "./Components/Blog/Blog";


const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route exact path="/blog" element={<BlogHome />} />
          <Route exact path="/blog/:title" element={<Blog />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;

And this is my vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['react-router-dom'], // Specify external dependencies here
    },
  },
});

Anyone know what could be causing this error? Let me know if you need to see any other part of my code!
File structure
├─ src
│  ├─ App.jsx
│  ├─ Components
│  │  ├─ Blog
│  │  │  ├─ Blog.jsx
│  │  │  ├─ BlogHeader.jsx
│  │  │  └─ BlogHome.jsx
│  ├─ main.jsx
│  └─ Utils
│     ├─ ArrayData.jsx
│     └─ slugify.js
└─ vite.config.js


show your folder structure of the project

I added to the post

I guess you gonna find the solution here

If this is an app and not a library, why put react-router-dom in rollupOptions.external?

This worked for me!
https://github.com/MMF-FE/vite-plugin-cdn-import
import cdn from 'vite-plugin-cdn-import'

    export default {
        plugins: [
            cdn({
                modules: ['react', 'react-dom'],
            }),
        ],
    }

